# What is the largest closed subset of $A = ]0,1] \cup\{2\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that it is not possible to define because the real numbers are an uncountable set? Obviously I see some options that are closed sets, but they aren't the largest ones, like $[1] \cup [2]$ or $[1/2,1] \cup [2]$, but as we tend to go closer to zero there is a problem.

Or should I say the largest possible subset is $[1/n,1] \cup {2}$? But then I'm confronted with the fact that the limit of 1/n as n goes to infinity is equal to zero.

Comment: Due to the uncountability of real numbers, there is no such "larger set", so you are right.

Comment: I agree that this is a correct conclusion, but I disagree that it has anything to do with the uncountability of $\Bbb R$. If we define closed sets in $\Bbb Q$ as $C\cap\Bbb Q$ where $C$ is closed in $\Bbb R$ (the natural quotient topology on $\Bbb Q$), then the exact same argument shows that there is no largest closed subset of $A\cap\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q$, even though $\Bbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: By the way, considering only the sequence $\{ [\frac1n,1] \cup \{2\}$ isn't enough to finish off the proof. One needs to prove the following: if $C\subset A$ is *any* closed set, then there exists another closed set $D\subset A$ that strictly contains $C$.